# Perform Function from another class on performDragOperation - Swift macOS

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop, core-animation, nsview

I'm having troubles trying to perform an animation function that is stored in a ViewController Class after the user drags and drops a file.

This is the animation code in my ViewController Class (that works fine if called from the same Class)

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

  func cancelAnim() {
        CANCELanimationView = AnimationView(animation: Animation.named("cancel"))
        CANCELanimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 103, y: 196, width: 45, height: 45)
        CANCELanimationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.addSubview(CANCELanimationView)
        CANCELanimationView.play()
    }

}
```

And this is where it should perform:

```
class DragContainer: NSView {

let mainVC = ViewController()

override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        guard let pasteboard = sender.draggingPasteboard.propertyList(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "NSFilenamesPboardType")) as? NSArray,
            let _ = pasteboard[0] as? String

            else { return false }

        let transferRef = userDef.string(forKey: "trasferMethod")
        let trasferRefURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: transferRef!)

        for files in pasteboard {
            let fileURLs = URL(fileURLWithPath: files as! String)
            print("--> \(files)")
            let endURL = trasferRefURL.appendingPathComponent(fileURLs.lastPathComponent)
            if fileURLs.hasDirectoryPath == true {
                _  = mainVC.contentsOf(folder: fileURLs.absoluteURL)
            } else {
                try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fileURLs.absoluteURL, to: endURL)
            }
        }
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.layer?.borderWidth = 0
        mainVC.cancelAnim() // <-- My Animation Function
        return true
    }

}
```

Anyway by doing this way I get the following error:

> 2020-05-05 17:40:31.158924+0200 Effektor[86633:18569343] *** Canceling
>   drag because exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' (reason
>   '-[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the
>   nibName: Effektor.ViewController in bundle (null).') was raised during
>   a dragging session

I'm using Swift 4 - macOS

Comment: `mainVC` is a new `ViewController`. Is this intentional?

Comment: `mainVC` should be the first ViewController where the function is stored